# Query using where condition in Android

Tags: android, android-cursor

I want to set a query to get names which cointain the a particular string (here constraint). 
SO I coded:

```
Cursor contactCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{Phone.DISPLAY_NAME}, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + "like + ?", new String[]{"%"+constraint+"%"}, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

But I get en error. 
I know that I'm close. 
Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo. Change this:

```
"like + ?"
```

to this:

```
" like ?"
```

(add a space in the front and remove the `+`).

Comment: Well, that's a little vague. Try the updated answer, but if you want more help post you logcat in your question.

Comment: here the exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT display_name FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1 AND mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2') AND (display_namelike ?) ORDER BY display_name ASC

Comment: It was the space notice `display_namelike ?` is wrong, but `display_name like ?` will compile.